# atmoshphere one to one chat

Tags: java, chat, atmosphere

I just started with Atmosphere for a simple chat application. I downloaded an example with java. This app is sending messages to all clients how can I send a message to a particular client. i think I am able to get uuid. Please someone guide me in right direction.

```
   @Config
@ManagedService(path = "/chat", atmosphereConfig = MAX_INACTIVE + "=9990000")
public class Chat {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Chat.class);

    @Inject
    private BroadcasterFactory factory;

    @Heartbeat
    public void onHeartbeat(final AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
        logger.trace("Heartbeat send by {}", event.getResource());
    }

    @Ready
    public void onReady(final AtmosphereResource r) {
        logger.info("Browser {} connected", r.uuid());
        if(null!=factory && null!=factory.getClass()){
            logger.info("BroadcasterFactory used {}", factory.getClass().getName());
        }

    }


    @Disconnect
    public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
        if (event.isCancelled()) {
            logger.info("Browser {} unexpectedly disconnected", event.getResource().uuid());
        } else if (event.isClosedByClient()) {
            logger.info("Browser {} closed the connection", event.getResource().uuid());
        }
    }


    @org.atmosphere.config.service.Message(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class}, decoders = {JacksonDecoder.class})
     @DeliverTo(DeliverTo.DELIVER_TO.BROADCASTER)
    public Message onMessage(Message message) throws IOException {
        logger.info("{} just send {}", message.getAuthor(), message.getMessage());
        return message;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Java class is incomplete.

Firstly, there is a missing variable which identify each chat room in your path :

```
 @ManagedService(path = "/chat/{chatRoomId}", atmosphereConfig = MAX_INACTIVE + "=9990000")
  public class Chat {

     @PathParam("chatRoomId")
     private String chatRoomId;

     [...]
  }
```

But, you can send all messages to only one socke connected.

Secondly, where is your script JS file to send and receive websocket message ?

This script JS file must contains these methods :

```
request.onOpen = function(request, response) {

};

request.onTransportFailure = function(request, response) {

};

request.onMessage = function(request, response) {

};

request.onClose = function(request, response) {

};

request.onError= function(request, response) {

};
request.onReconnect = function(request, response) {

};
```

The most important is to declare the structure of your request :

```
var socket = atmosphere;
var subSocket;
var transport = 'websocket';

var request = { 
    url: document.location.toString() + 'chat' + chatRoomId,
    contentType : "application/json",
    logLevel : 'debug',
    transport : transport ,
    trackMessageLength : true,
    reconnectInterval : 5000 
};
```